# How to estimate a definite integral using Taylor series

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, approximation

I have a problem that asks Evaluate to five decimal places using the taylor series for the definite integral. 
  $$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{e^x}{x} dx$$
I don't get how to do this, given that the minute you even do the first term, you have more than 4 decimal places. How can I possible know how many terms to use to approximate 4 decimal places. For example

the taylor series representation of:
$$\frac{e^x}{x}$$

is $$\frac{1}{x}+1+\frac{x^2}{2!x}+\frac{x^3}{3!x}+....$$

so I know now to integrate that statement which gives me the following series to solve for

$$\left.ln(x)+x+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{3!*3}+\frac{x^4}{4!*4}+\right|_1^2$$

as you can see that is only the first 6 terms for the series being integrated and then we would solve those for 2 minus those solved at 1 to have an answer. My question is: is there an easy way to know how many terms I need to go to find this answer. I know with alternating series you go until the place value you are looking to do doesnt change its answer anymore with more terms added, but with this kind of series I do not know how far to take this.

Thank you

Comment: Check out Taylor's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem )

Comment: You will need all of the terms for an "exact" answer.  However this sequence converges quickly.  So you do not need very many for a reasonably precise estimate.

Comment: my true question would be: yes, I can get to convergence but technically $$ln2-ln1$$ is an approximation of this definite integral. It has a huge error, but still is an approximation. How many terms do you have to go until you know you are truly within 5 decimal places of accuracy? @DougM

Comment: you cant integrate termwise and ignore the denominator like that.

Comment: @NickPeterson. I checked out that wikipedia page before. I see where they approxmiate the value $$e^x$$, but why did they only use a second order taylor expansion to do it with. Is there something special. Can I do that with mine, or do I have to go to a different degree. They used the remainder of the second order but did not specify why they did that. Why not use 1st level, or 3rd. I am confused about when to use what.

Comment: @mathreadler. The denominator isn't getting ignored. $$\frac{1}{x}=lnx , 1=x , \frac{x}{2!}=\frac{x^2}{2*2!}, \frac{x^2}{3!} = \frac{x^3}{3!*3}$$

Comment: You're better off expanding around a point in-between 1 and 2. If you want an alternating series, you can expand around x = 2. Expanding around an arbitrary point $x = u$ yields a series expansion that depends on $u$ for the answer, but you can then exploit the fact that the exact answer must be independent of $u$. The optimal choice of $u$ for the truncated series is that value that makes the derivative w.r.t. $u$ vanish. This is called the "principle of minimal sensitivity".

Comment: If you sum the first n terms of the polynomial, the error will be less than $\frac {2^{(n-1)}}{n(n!)}$

Comment: @Washington state one : $\frac{x^3}{6x}$?

Comment: @mathreadler  Yes, that becomes $$\frac{x^2}{3!}$$ whose derivative would be $$\frac{x^3}{3!*3}$$ You simplify a fraction before taking the derivative.

Comment: @Washington state one : The term is still in your expression after the integration right after $x$.

Comment: 6 terms yields 3.0591164 when expanding around the optimal point $x = 1.47734482762883703103370206062\cdots + 0.114072871768267137264762623200\cdots i$, the error turns out to be about $10^{-7}$ so the last decimal is off by 1.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^{x}}{x}\,dx = \frac{e^2}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\,dx=\frac{e^2}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^n}\int_{0}^{1}x^n e^{-x}\,dx $$
where the terms of the last series behave like $\frac{1}{n 2^n}$ for large values of $n$. It follows that the approximation
$$ \frac{e^2}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{15}\frac{1}{2^n}\int_{0}^{1}x^n e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{e (-2054417761371+755778071552 e)}{32768}=\color{green}{3.05911}4093$$
is correct up to the fifth place. An alternative approach is to consider the integral
$$\begin{align*} \int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^x}{x}(x-1)^{8}(2-x)^{8}\,dx = 16e(148414279984 - 54598562389e)+256\int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx \end{align*}$$
where the LHS is positive but bounded by $\frac{e^2}{2^{16}}$. It follows that:
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx \approx \frac{e(54598562389e-148414279984)}{16}=\color{green}{3.059116}4861\ldots$$
is a simpler approximation, correct up to the sixth place.